# Ember data Doing a general search on a Model after some instances have been added to a relationship

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have these basic models (super simplified to show the problem):

```
App.Alert = DS.Model.extend({
    recipients: DS.hasMany('App.Person')
})

App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr("string")
})
```

Then I try and execute the following:

```
var alert = App.Alert.createRecord()
var persons = App.Person.find({page: 1, pageSize: 10})
alert.get("recipients").pushObjects(persons.toArray())
var persons2 = App.Person.find({page: 1, pageSize: 10})
```

At which point I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `loadedData` on <App.Person:ember592:121878738770883> while in state rootState.loaded.updated.uncommitted. Called with undefined
```

So it seems that if I add an object to a relationship, it changes to state uncommitted. Question is, how should I proceed when I have a model with hasMany, and I wish to show a search dialog where the user can add more persons to the alert? The search will generally result in loading some objects that have already been added to the alert, and are thus dirty.

Current workaround is to just keep what is going to be added as recipients in the controller, and add them before saving. However, if I do that, and the server does not approve the submit, I need to rollback only the recipients to allow the user to continue to edit.

What is the approach for managing a hasMany relationship where you also wish to let the user search for records of the same type.

Comment: If you can provide working fiddle, that will help.. to understand better.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

How is the response being formatted by the call to `App.Person.find`?

It would appear that the response is not getting returned correctly (either missing a key or in an incorrect JSON format)

I.e the `Called with undefined` suggests a null or un-serializeable return object.